# Algorithm for efficient identification of bipartite graph

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search, bipartite

I'm looking for an algorithm to efficiently determine if a given graph (implemented either as an adyacency matrix or as an adyacency list — the one that makes the algorithm run faster) is bipartite or not.

I'm aware that a slight modification of BFS algorithm can suit this purpose, but I haven't been able to lower BFS's time-complexity of O(|E|+|V|).

I'd expect to find an algorithm that is a bit faster, taking advantage o the fact that a bipartite graph lacks cicles with an odd number of edges.

Does anyone know such algorithm or have any suggestion to address this problem?

Comment: It would be a real trick to get better than O(|E|+|V|) because going faster than that means you can't look at all the vertices and edges. There's a simple adversary argument that says there's no way to do this.

Comment: I can be wrong, but I really doubt that such algorithm can exist, you have to check each vertex and each edge to prove that graph is really bipartite